# Unmarshal json to a array from post request

Tags: json, go

see below my

main.go

```
type Data struct {
        unit []string `json:"unit"`
     }
 func receive(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

  dec := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
  for {
    var d Data
    if err := dec.Decode(&d); err == io.EOF {
        break
    } else if err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
    }
    log.Printf("%s\n", d.unit)
  }
}
```

Error that is throwed: "json: cannot unmarshal array into GO value of type main.Data"

moj.js

```
 $(function(){
 $('#start').on('click', function(){
 var i;
 var j = 0;

 for (i = 0; i < result.length; i++){

 if(result[i] == null){  
  }else if(result[i]==""){
  }else{
  lookup[j] = result[i];
  j++
  }
 }
 $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/start',
        data: '[{"unit":"'+lookup+'"}]',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function () {
           alert("Data posted.")
        },
        error: function(){
          alert('Error posting data.')
        }
    });
  });
});
```

The "json" that I send looks like: [{"unit":"something"}].

In the console I can see the data has been posted like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things:

1. You are unmarshalling a slice of Data rather than a slice of 'unit'.
2. Make the 'unit' field public so that it is visible by reflection to the Decoder

See: https://play.golang.org/p/4kfIQTXqYi

```
type Data struct {
    Unit string `json:"unit"`
}

func receive(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    dec := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
    for {
        var d []Data
        if err := dec.Decode(&d); err == io.EOF {
            break
        } else if err != nil {
            log.Println(err)
        }
        log.Printf("%s\n", d.Unit)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks man, this was usefull. Who would say that something like this would take me so much time.

Comment: No problem.  I've found that the error messages in Go are actually very accurate and useful, unlike other languages.  In your case, it was pretty spot on.